# Develop responsive layouts in angular 2 material using flex layouts

Tags: angular-material2

How to develop responsive layouts in angular 2 material using flex layouts.
In angular material we use the code below for responsive layouts on desktop & mobile view.
ex.

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-wrap="" layout-align="center center">
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100">
    </div>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100">
    </div>
    <div flex="33" flex-xs="100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using it at this times. It is really comfortable.

To install it: [Click](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

More info is here: [Click](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki)

To using it in css with examples: [Click](http://cssreference.io/flexbox/)

And an online example: [Click](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

You just need to determine where you use flex-container and flex-item class. And you need to set fxLayout and fxLayoutAlign directives true. It handles rest of work.

I use it with @angular 2.4.3

Comment: Where could I find a code provided for the responsive examples ?